# Enviar datos de JavaScript a PHP, para utilizarlo en FPDF

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, fpdf

buenas tardes, tengo un problema que ya me tiene de cabeza, por mas que intento no logro resolverlo, tengo un HTML, del cual quiero enviar datos a un PHP, para que este último lo procese y con la clase FPDF cree un fichero PDF, los datos provendran de unos controles en HTML, es por eso que utilizaré JavaScript para enviar dichos datos al PHP. Cuando lo ejecuto solo me manda un monton de caracteres a mi pagina y no crea el PDF, hay alguna forma de solucionar ese problema? Mi codigo es el siguiente:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>              
    </head>
    <body> 

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js"></script>

        <button type="button" onclick="GenerarPDF()">click</button>                    
        <div id="resulta"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
function GenerarPDF() {

    $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'pdf.php',
                data: {"saludo": "hola"}, //aquí le pasaré datos de controles de HTML

                success: function (result) {
                    $('#resulta').html(result);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

pdf.php

```
<?php

require_once('PDF/fpdf/fpdf.php');

$saludo = $_POST['saludo'];


$pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter');
$pdf->AddFont('Courier', '');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Courier', '', 11);
$pdf->Cell(50,10,$saludo);
$pdf->Output();
```

De antemano muchas gracias a todos.

P. D. Trabajo con Windows 7 y PHP7.

Comment: deberias incluir: header("Content-type:application/pdf"); ...en tu php

Comment: en dónde incluyo ese código? ya intente ponerlo antes del Output() pero sigue saliendo error.

Comment: mira esto te va ayudar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679756/show-a-pdf-files-in-users-browser-via-php-perl

Comment: hice algo parecido pero con python y el pdf lo abria en una nueva ventana o forzar la descarga..

Answer (score 0):

Los caracteres que te retorna es la codificación del PDF:
Para evitar esto tienes que agregar los parametros a output

```
$pdf->Output("F","..tu ruta de archivo con nombre");
```

F es una propiedad de FPDF que le dice a la clase que guarde el archivo de forma local, luego esta el nombre de archivo, en este pones la ruta donde quieras guardarlo.

Los metodos permitidos son:

```
I: envía el fichero al navegador de forma que se usa la extensión (plug in) si está disponible.
D: envía el fichero al navegador y fuerza la descarga del fichero con el nombre especificado por name.
F: guarda el fichero en un fichero local de nombre name.
S: devuelve el documento como una cadena.
```

[Documentación](http://www.fpdf.org/)